# delete all but 10 newest files linux but I am facing No such file or directory exception

Tags: linux

I am using the following command while I am sudoing the correct user;

```
ls -t1 /cs/wlsconfig/wls10.3.2/servers/cmt/logs | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -r
```

But I get the following exception while using this command;

```
rm: cannot remove `cmt.log00045': No such file or directory
```

Irrespective of the fact that running the following command does return results with a list of files;

```
ls -t1 /cs/wlsconfig/wls10.3.2/servers/cmt/logs | tail -n +10
```

Any leads would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepend the path to your `rm` call or change into the directory first. Try this:

```
cd /cs/wlsconfig/wls10.3.2/servers/cmt/logs
ls -t1 | tail -n +10 | xargs rm -r
```

However this won't work with file names containing spaces. This is one of the reasons why it is a [bad idea to parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Take a look at these similar questions and their solutions:

- [Shell script to count files, then remove oldest files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960022/shell-script-to-count-files-then-remove-oldest-files)
- [Delete all but the most recent X files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785/delete-all-but-the-most-recent-x-files-in-bash)
- [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-to-delete-directories-older-than-n-days)
- [Delete files older than 10 days using shell script in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489398/delete-files-older-than-10-days-using-shell-script-in-unix)